# How to dynamically create controls with bindings to user settings on a window

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, binding, settings

I have a window to which I am dynamically adding a StackPanel and to this StackPanel a Label and TextBox for each User Setting. I was hoping to 2 way bind the Value from the user setting to the value in the TextBox so that I can edit any user settings at run-time that were added at design time.

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Settings
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitSettings();
        }
        private void InitSettings()
        {
            Window window = this;
            StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();

            foreach (SettingsProperty settingsProperty in Properties.Settings.Default.Properties)
            {
                Binding binding = new Binding();
                binding.Source = settingsProperty;
                binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
                binding.Path = new PropertyPath(settingsProperty.Name);

                Label label = new Label();
                label.Content = settingsProperty.Name;

                TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
                textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);

                textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();

                stackPanel.Children.Add(label);
                stackPanel.Children.Add(textBox);


            }
            window.Content = stackPanel;
        }
    }
}
```

The window looks as I expect but the values from my user settings are not displayed and I cannot figure whats wrong in my code or if this is even possible.

Comment: This approach won't work, because the Binding assumes that there is a property in each SettingsProperty that is named like the value of its Name property. That's not the case. Note that SettingsProperty [*represents metadata about an individual configuration property*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingsproperty(v=vs.110).aspx), but doesn't hold the actual property value.

Comment: You may create a dictionary of name/value pairs by `Settings.Default.Properties.Cast<SettingsProperty>().ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => Settings.Default[p.Name])`. Then simply assign that to the ItemsSource property of a DataGrid.